# How to retrieve the values from the database with column name using python script?

Tags: python, select, typeerror

I need to retrieve values from the database for the column names specified. The below code I've tried,

```
import pyodbc

def get_db_data():
    cursor = getConnection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from student")
    return cursor

cur = get_db_data()
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row["student_name"])
```

I'm facing below error

```
TypeError: row indices must be integers, not str
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a column by name, you should specify it as an attribute of the row rather than an index:

```
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row.student_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the pyodbc documentation "Row objects are similar to tuples, but they also allow access to columns by name". You can try row[0] or row.student_name (Assuming column index for student_name is 0)

```
import pyodbc

def get_db_data():
    cursor = getConnection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from student")
    return cursor

cur = get_db_data()
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row[0])
```